# Term for a roof pitch viewed from inside (Image included)

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder what an English speaking person would call a roof pitch viewed from inside the house like seen in the image below:

[image]

For example, how would I describe the location of the desk beneath the window if I want to make sure that my reader understands that it is situated beneath a roof pitch?

> The desk is placed beneath ___

Comment: I'd just call it a sloping ceiling; but I've heard that area called "in the eaves".

Comment: You can also call it a [*slanted ceiling*](https://www.google.it/search?q=slanting+ceiling&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCAQsARqFQoTCJLWgr3r5MgCFeadcgodeiYP4A&biw=1366&bih=677#tbm=isch&q=%22slanted+ceiling%22)

Comment: This seems more a question about architecture than about English.

Comment: @WS2, architectural vocabulary is part of English so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK True, although assuming "an English speaking person" is also an architect is an unusual assumption. I don't think the overwhelming majority of people have ever thought about this situation enough to be more than vaguely aware that there might be an adjectival phrase to describe it. In other words, OP, if you plan on using whatever expression you get from here in casual conversation with anyone who isn't an architecture fetishist, prepare to get quizzical looks.

Comment: @ParthianShot, Have you looked at my answer? Anyone who has a roof like this knows, "under the rafters" as I have demonstrated with numerous examples. You don't have to be an architect. (Some of those quotes appear to be from advertising copywriters and they are renowned for their ignorance of anything technical)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I suppose that's fair, although it's still pretty uncommon (at least in U.S. English), and although I recognized the word and was aware it's part of the interior of a roof, I wasn't sure what type of beam it was referring to. I actually had it confused with "collar beam", to be honest, until I actually looked it up.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what the question is asking for. Does the word you're seeking describe the shape of all parts of the roof seen from inside this room (including both sides of the roof) or are you trying to describe just the part of the roof near the desk, without regard for what kind of ceiling exists on the other side of the room?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the UK at least, the desk in the picture is in an area known as [**"in the eaves"**](http://hoa.org.uk/advice/guides-for-homeowners/i-am-improving/loft-conversion-where-do-i-start/),

> Also think about storage, as built-in space can often be included, especially in the eaves. (-- Home Owners Alliance website)

or [**"under the eaves"**](http://www.houseandgarden.co.uk/interiors/loft-conversions/curtained-bed-sloped-ceiling):

> A bed tucked behind a curtain under the eaves makes for a charming den. (-- *House & Garden* magazine, Dec 2012)

In my experience, it would be understood that "in the eaves" means an area with reduced ceiling height - no-one would expect to be able to stand upright there.

Historically, the [eaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaves) themselves are the external parts of a pitched roof which overhang the outside wall. By proximity, the name is now associated with the part of the inside roof space *nearest* to the eaves.

**EDIT** to clairify - this only applies to the part of the space next to the (low) wall. Your question asks about the ceiling and could refer to anywhere in that space. I'd just call that a "sloping ceiling".

Comment: @downvoter - go on, give me a clue.

Comment: +1... but only because you specifically call out that the "historical" (or, as I would have worded it, "technical") definition of eaves is the external parts, but is taken by many to include internal parts. [At a guess, the downvoter may be a technical purist and dislike this usage of "eaves".]

Comment: Also, I think that "sloping ceiling" is possibly the best answer.

Comment: In my experience with American English, I think most people would colloquially understand "under the eaves" to mean any place underneath the sloping ceiling of the top floor of a building with a sloped roof, regardless of proximity to the outside wall.

Comment: Agreed with @recognizer, I can't say I frequently use or hear the word *eaves* here in America, but it **was** what came to mind when I read the question.

Answer (score 6):

That is a ***[gable roof](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pitched-roof)*** or *pitched roof*:

> - a roof sloping downward in two parts at an angle from a central ridge, so as to leave a gable at each end.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Seen form the inside it is called  *[gable ceiling](http://www.ehow.com/info_12182222_gable-ceiling.html)*:

> - A home with a pitched roof may allow the owner to create interior spaces with gable ceilings. Gable ceilings rise upward in a triangular shape creating a sense of space, grandeur and openness. However, some gable ceilings can also feel cramped and uncomfortable. A gable ceilings utilizes a peaked or triangular roof and may not be the best ceiling choice for every home.

[The Gable Roof](http://www.hip-home.com/tips/weekly-tips/the-gable-roof.html): History of a Common Roof Construction Style.

> - The gable roof style has its roots in some very impressive Greek and Roman architecture.

(www.hip-home.com)

Comment: While true for the roofspace pictured, it should be mentioned that the situation would also apply under a [*hipped*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_roof) roof - i.e. one without gables.

Comment: @JHCL - that's architecture, OP is not asking how to make one, just what it is called. A good  interior decorator could make any kink of  ceiling from any kind of  roof .

Comment: Although you mentioned "pitched", your answer appeared to limit the application to "gables", with the examples and links. But there are no gables [here](http://www.ashdaleconstruction.com/img/l0ft1.jpg), for instance.

Comment: This doesn't usefully distinguish the restricted height above the desk from the full-height part of the room, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Josh61: That isn't really true. You aren't going to put this roof in a cube shaped room or the first floor of a two story. You also aren't going to turn this room into a cube shape.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that picture does not show a [gabled roof](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/photos/0,,1213138,00.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am an English (American) speaker and an architect, and these are my answers to the two questions *I think* you are asking:

1. What term would I use to describe the ceiling (the roof pitch)? It depends on many factors ... contexts of the usage, physical context of the space, intent of your usage, etc., but these would be most likely:

   - sloped ceiling
   - sloped (or vaulted) ceiling of the attic space

I would not call this a gabled ceiling. In fact, I have never used or heard of the term, and if an eHow entry is the source I would be skeptical.

2. How would I describe the location of the desk beneath the window? Once again, context is important but probably more important is the intent. Is the description to help sell a house or is it for a painting bid? In the absence of any intent, my literal response would be "the desk is located beneath a sloped skylight in an attic room".

Comment: I don't think I'd call the specific picture from the OP a *vaulted ceiling*. To me that conjures up an image of full head height at the edges of the room and "extra" height in the middle of the room.

Comment: I would not use vaulted without the qualifier "of an attic space". Vaulted by itself implies (to me) something taller and perhaps grander. That being said, "sloped ceiling" does not describe a ceiling that slopes up from two sides to meet at a high point in the middle. "Vault" doesn't exclusively describe that condition, but it includes that condition and is probably the most common interpretation.

Comment: @AndyT, vaulted seems perfectly correct to me as the term refers to shape and has very little to do with height. Although your impressions may be true that vaulted ceilings often give you much more headroom than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer**

*The desk is placed beneath the **rafters**.*

> *Upstairs, nestled **beneath the rafters**, the charming bedroom
>   contains a double bed.*  [Museum View penthouse Amsterdam](http://www.only-apartments.com/en/amsterdam/museumviewpenthouseamsterdam_93373/)

Even thought the rafters are covered over with plasterboard you are still under the rafters.

**Examples**

[squeeze shelves under the rafters](http://www.thesnug.com/shelves-under-the-rafters-895931220.html)

[Cabinet under the rafters](http://lumberjocks.com/projects/59620)

[Kids’ Rooms: Under the Rafters](http://www.kidspacestuff.com/blog/2013/12/kids-rooms-under-the-rafters/)

[Up high under the rafters, this white on white bed easily doubles as a reading nook by day.](http://vinnord.blogspot.co.uk/2011_11_01_archive.html)

[No hay now, just a pretty bed under the rafters](http://www.sawdays.co.uk/britain/england/suffolk/the-coach-house)

[The loft bedroom is a romantic getaway with a queen bed under the rafters.](http://www.pacificpalmsholidays.com.au/accommodation/1783)

Comment: Everything in that room is _beneath the rafters_ regardless of ceiling height.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Useless. In fact everything in my house is beneath the rafters, some of it just happens to also be below the ceiling/floor joists too.

Comment: Suppose you asked me where to find something, and I said, "Beneath your bed," but the sought-for object was actually on a table on a lower floor, you would rightly accuse me of speaking falsely even if the table and bed happened to be perfectly aligned on a vertical axis. The desk is correctly described as being under the rafters, although its proximity to the wall implies that "under the eaves" is a more precise (though perhaps less architecturally accurate) description.

Comment: @DavidK - I take your point, my previous comment gave a rather stupid example.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "what is the roof pitch called". It's looking for a term that describes this angle of ceiling/roof; your answer describes a way to refer to *rooms* that have this angle of ceiling/roof.

Comment: @TylerH "Beneath the rafters" would describe only what is directly under the sloped ceiling, not the whole room--unless you have a room like the one in your photo, where there is almost no place to stand that is _not_ under a sloped ceiling. In a room with a mostly flat ceiling interrupted by the roof only near one wall, only things next to that wall would be "beneath the rafters". I think this answer is precisely what you asked for, though not necessarily what you want.

Comment: @AndyT Actually I thought your comment was quite clever. It points out that common usage of the word "beneath" has a bit of slippery ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidK Um, I'm not the question asker. Regardless, the whole context of this question is for rooms like the one in the photo above whose walls are almost entirely angled.

Comment: @TylerH I interpreted the question in a very different way, referring specifically to the part of the ceiling near the desk, so that the other side of the roof was irrelevant. Perhaps we need the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: @TylerH, As a matter of fact I answered the question quite precisely. The OP asked for a completion of the sentence, "*The desk is placed beneath ___*" and I did that  in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK If we accept that reasoning, then it's simply a poor answer. It's also beneath the sky, but that's also not very useful to say. Everything in a house is beneath the rafters, since those are the beams that hold up the roof, which ostensibly covers the whole house.

Comment: @TylerH, This is not Logic Stack Exchange, it's English Language & ***Usage*** Stack Exchange. I gave plenty of examples of *actual usage* in real-life situations.  If people are illogical in their use of the word rafters, that is not my responsibility. It is a commonly used expression and that is why I provided it. Lighten up a little?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a "vaulted ceiling".

Vaulted means arched, but when it come to roofs and ceilings it also refers to any sort of triangular truss as well. The truss can be hollow as in your image or consist of cross members of varying degrees of complexity.

Here are [some other examples of vaulted ceilings](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vaulted%20ceiling&espv=2&biw=1249&bih=933&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIrc3dhOnlyAIVApmICh25-gG-) as a simple google image search which indicates how commonly the phrase is used to refer to such an arrangement.

"The desk is placed beneath a vaulted ceiling."

Or even:

"The room where the desk is situated has a vaulted ceiling."

Comment: more generally, the desk is tucked under the roof vault.

Answer (score 1):

The desk is placed beneath a **gambrel shaped ceiling** (or put more simply, a [**sloping**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sloping+ceiling%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csloping%20ceiling%3B%2Cc0) or **attic ceiling**).

> gambrel roof:  a roof with a lower steeper slope and an upper less
>   steep one on each of its two sides [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gambrel?show=1)

Comment: The OP picture isn't of a gambrel ceiling as you've defined it (or as I understand it).

Answer (score 1):

My impulse would be to say "in the garret" or "under a garret window." The definition of [garret window](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/garret_window) is apparently "A skylight that lies along the slope of the roof," so this seems to fit well.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your desk is next to a *dormer* window in an upper *half-storey.*</s>

Your desk sits within an upper *half-storey*.  It also happens to be next to a *skylight* style window.

Sources:

- <s>[dormer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dormer) at Merrian-Webster</s>
- [skylight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skylight) at Merrian-Webster
- [half-storey](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/half-story) at dictionary.com

And just for fun, here's a discussion about [story vs. storey](http://grammarist.com/spelling/storey-story/).  Apparently, as an American, I am supposed to leave the "e" out, but I learned it with an "e" and I am keeping it!

Comment: You might want to re-read that definition of dormer.

Comment: @JHCL- Agree. That's not a dormer window in OP's picture.

Comment: @cobaltduck - Personally I'd call them velux windows rather than skylights. "Skylight" to me implies in a horizontal ceiling rather than a sloped one. That said velux is a brand name, do it's not a *great* description to use. I can't think of a generic name for it offhand. [Burhan's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/283417/91730) does suggest that skylight is valid in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, how would I describe the location of the desk beneath the
>   window if I want to make sure that my reader understands that it is
>   situated beneath a roof pitch?

The desk is located under a [*skylight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylight_(window)) which is:

> A window set in a roof or ceiling at the same angle.

Its not important to describe the roof, since the fact that its angled is part of the description of the window.

Comment: Hi Burhan, Welcome to EL&U. Great answer. Good thing that you have included a link too. Most of the time, this is a mistake which new people commit while posting their answers. You have done your homework well, I guess. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The window just happened to be in the first picture I grabbed that showed a pitched roof, though. My question is not about windows at all.

Comment: @Burhan - it is important to describe the roof, because a skylight is not necessarily in a sloped ceiling. If the ceiling is horizontal, then a horizontal window in it is "at the same angle" as the ceiling.